# KNIME 3.2 Tableau Node error

Tags: sdk, tableau-api, knime, tde

I installed the new (in KNIME 3.2) Tableau extension,  installed and configured the dependencies as per instructions in the node description (Tableau SDK and Visual Basic Redistributable), and tried to create an extract. My repeated attempts throw the same error:

> ERROR Tableau Writer (TDE) 0:8        Execute failed: Timeout
>    - IPC_NamedPipe::Select(WaitForMultipleObjects)

Does anyone have any tips on how to diagnose this further?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved with the help of Tableau engineer.

The cause was the presense of an older Tableau API kit which is now superceded by a newer SDK kit, which now has the combined API & SDK functionality.

The PATH variable was pointing to both older API and newer SDK kits, and they had some binaries with the same name.

Removing the older kit fixed the issue.