# KNIME 3.2 Tableau Node dependancy error

Tags: c++, knime

I am getting a different error from this post ([KNIME 3.2 Tableau Node error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363981/knime-3-2-tableau-node-error)).  I believe my problem precedes his.  I suspect my problem is in setting up my dependencies and PATH variables.

- I have downloaded the Tableau SDK, and placed it both in the KNIME Workspace, and in Tableau's program files.  I have configured the linked resources page of the KNIME to point to each file individually and to the bin directory.

[image]

- In addition, I have edited the Windows System variable PATH and added in the new \BIN\ directory;
- I have also downloaded the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013, the 32 bit version I found from here:
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

When I execute I first get a library not found.  Then on subsequent executions I get the error "Execute failed: Could not initialize class com.tableausoftware.extract.ExtractAPI" 
[image]

Does anyone know how to properly set up KNIME's environment to successfully use the Tableau connector?

Comment: I have attempted this on my 64 bit machine and I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay here are the steps I used in order.

- Download the Java version of the Tableau SDK for Windows:
  https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/help.htm#SDK/tableau_sdk_installing.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____3
- Unzip that file into a directory called SDK in the workspace you are using.  For me this was  C:\Users\<'user name'>\knime-workspace\
- Update environment variables for "Path" on your system and in KNIME add a linked folder resource (Preferences -> Workspace -> Linked Resources)
  Point both towards the \bin\ sub-directory.
- THEN installed the  "Microsoft Visual Basic 2013 Redistributables" file.

Comment: Not sure if the order matters; I believe my original problem was my "Path" variable did not point to the "\bin\" directory